React passing objects vs multiple variables in props
I'm looking to pass an object with lots of variables from the parent to child.
For example,I want to pass Person to the child
Person: firstName,lastName, dateOfBirth, nationality, phone, address (nested)
Address: firstLine,secondLine, zip,state, country

What is the recommended way of approaching this out of the two approaches below?
child({person,updatePerson})

vs
child({firstName,updateFirstName,lastName, updateLastName..etc})

This issue I have with passing the object is that it breaks encapsulation and you need to be careful around copying the object. However, the alternative becomes quite cumbersome to include the property and an update method for each propetty.
e.g.
function onUpdateZip(zip){
   newPerson={...person};
   newAddress={...person.address};
   newPerson.address=newAddress;
   newAddress.zip=zip;
   updatePerson(newPerson);
}

vs
function onUpdateZip(zip){
   updateZip(zip);
}


I prefer passing an object, because the object means a namespace or context. So I know the context of the properties and no variable naming conflicts.
If you want to do immutable updates, you can use immer.js, it will update the data in a more convenient way. See React & Immer
So the <Child/> component will has below props:
type Person = {
  firstName: string;
  //...others
}

export type ChildProps = {
  person: Person;
  onPersonChange(person: Person): void;
}

const Child = ({ person }: ChildProps) => {
  
  return <div>
    <p>firstName: {person.firstName}</p>
  </div>
}


Very useful answer, would be great to illustrate the example with immer.js to update first name.
